# Using WebStorm with ASP.NET. How to separate front end with back end and integrate them?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio-2012, webstorm

I'd love to use WebStorm for my project. However, the project is based on ASP.NET. Is it even possible to use WebStorm for this purpose? I read this article http://wildermuth.com/2014/12/13/Visual_Studio_and_WebStorm_Am_I_Mad , but comments below from experienced users say that there are problems when work with Visual Studio and WebStorm together. What's your experience and how do you work between the tools?

Comment: The way I read those comments from experienced users, they seem to mostly be in favor of using WebStorm with VS.  We use them both together.

Comment: [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is the asp.net cousin to WebStorm, designed to work with VS, and uses the same plugins as WebStorm and other JetBrains IDEs.

Comment: @ClementMandragora *"and uses the same plugins as WebStorm and other JetBrains IDEs"* That is not correct. All IDEs (e.g. WebStorm) and plugins to them are written in Java .. while ReSharper is done in C# (?) but definitely not Java. So if they both have the same plugin, it has to be coded 2 times for different platforms.